How to build specific platform/archetecture image with Spring Boot 3.x bootBuildImage task
I am trying to build "linux/amd64" image for deployent in k8s in cloud, but since i am on M1 Pro, image produced is "linux/arm64" and cannot be deployed in my case.
When it is built with ci, on linux machine, all is fine, but for debugging purposes it is not convenient to run ci every time to see it in cloud
gradle task looks like this:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.24"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.24"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.24"
    id("org.springframework.boot.aot") version "3.3.2"
}

....

tasks.named<BootBuildImage>("bootBuildImage") {
    val imageNameValue = System.getenv("BACKEND_IMAGE_NAME")
    imageName.set(imageNameValue)

    // Enable CDS and Spring AOT
    environment.put("BP_JVM_CDS_ENABLED", "true")
    environment.put("BP_SPRING_AOT_ENABLED", "true")

    environment.put("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE", "bootBuildProfile")

    // For multi arch (Apple Silicon) support
    builder.set("paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-buildpackless-tiny")
    buildpacks.set(listOf("paketobuildpacks/java"))
}

what I am missing and how to force it to build required image type?

use buildx (1) docker buildx create --use (2) docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t yourusername/yourimagename:tag --load . (3) docker buildx imagetools inspect yourusername/yourimagename:tag (4) docker run yourusername/yourimagename:tag (5) linux/arm64 is for M1

@life888888 it assumes you have dockerfile, which is not the case.
first it will fail on (2) blaming multiplatform, then on (3) will try to load Dockerfile that is not exist.

An imagePlatform option has been added to the Spring Boot Gradle (and Maven) plugin for this purpose. The option will be released in Spring Boot 3.4.0, and is available now in snapshot builds.
plugins {
    ...
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.4.0-SNAPSHOT"
    id("org.springframework.boot.aot") version "3.4.0-SNAPSHOT"
    ...
}

....

tasks.named<BootBuildImage>("bootBuildImage") {
    ...

    // For multi arch (Apple Silicon) support
    builder.set("paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-buildpackless-tiny")
    buildpacks.set(listOf("paketobuildpacks/java"))
    imagePlatform.set("linux/amd64")
}

